# how to read .sql file in java tso that a query can be run after connecting to the DB

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a file "queries.sql" in my java project, which has the below queries from a particular DB schema.

```
query1=select * from HR.EMPLOYEES;
query2=select * from HR.departments;
```

Now through Java code, I am connecting to the DB and trying to run query1.
Even though the connection to DB is established, the query 1 is not being fetched from the ".sql" file.

Below is my Java code to create the connection to DB.

```
    //step1 load the driver class  
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
    //step2 create  the connection object  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(getConnection,userame,passWord);  
    //step3 create the statement object  
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    //step4 execute query  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(LoadSQLQuery.query1());  // it fails here
```

Because below is my code where I am trying to extract query1

```
  try {
      prop = new Properties();
      input = new FileInputStream("path to .sql file");
      prop.load(input);           

        }  catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



   public static String query1()
   {
   query1 = System.getProperty("query1").toLowerCase();
   return query1;
   }
```

Comment: `System.getProperty` doesn't access `props`... You need to use `props.getProperty`.

Comment: What on Earth was I thinking when I used system.getproperty.

Comment: Seems like o copy pasted from my other project in a hurry.